# G be finite and solvable and M is maximal subgroup of G with $core_G(M)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I am reading "Algebra, a graduate course"   of Martin Isaacs. While looking at exercises of chapter 8 ("Solvable and Nilpotent Groups"), I couldn't solve the part (d) of the following question.

> 8.2 Let $G$ be finite and solvable and suppose $M<G$ is a maximal subgroup and $core_G(M)=1$. Let $N$ be minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Show the following:
>
> a.  $ NM=G$ and $N\cap M=1$.
>
> b.  $ C_M(N)=1$.
>
> c.  $ N=C_G(N)$.
>
> d.  $ N$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Firstly, $NM$ is a subgroup of $G$, because $N$ is normal, and  $N\cap M < N$ because $core_G(M)=1$ (So $M$ cannot contain any normal subgroup of $G$).

$\Rightarrow NM > M \Rightarrow NM=G=MN$.

$N$ is solvable because $G$ is solvable
$\Rightarrow N'<N \Rightarrow N'=1 $ because $N$ is minimal normal subgroup. So N is abelian. If $t\in N\cap M$, then for any $n\in N$ $n^{-1}tn=t \Rightarrow t\in core_G(M) \Rightarrow t=1$ (Because $core_G(M)=\bigcap_{g\in G} M^g=\bigcap_{mn\in G} M^{mn}=\bigcap_{n\in N} M^n$). So $N\cap M=1$.

If $s\in C_M(N)$,
then for any $n\in N$ $n^{-1}sn=s \Rightarrow s\in core_G(M) \Rightarrow s=1$. So $C_M(N)=1$ and this implies $C_G(N)=N$ because $N$ is abelian and $G=MN$.

But I couldn't prove the uniqueness of minimal normal subgroup.

Comment: If $L$ is another minimal normal subgroup of $G$ then $L \cap N = 1$, so $L \le C_G(N)$ contradicting c.

Comment: Why  $L\leq C_G(N)$ ?

Comment: $[L,N] \le L \cap N = 1$.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this fact . This is very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Your deduction in part (b) seems invalid. Afterall, suppose $m\in M$ commutes with all $n$, then $m\in\bigcap nMn^{-1}$, and this does not imply $m\in core_G(M)$.

Comment: $M^m = M$ for all $m\in M$ which implies $M^{mn}=M^n$ for any $mn\in G$ . So it should be the case if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Oops... I wasn't aware of the fact that $NM=G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $K$ is another minimal normal subrgoup, then $K \cap N=1$, whence $K$ and $N$ commute ($[K,N]=1$). So $K \subseteq N$ by c. And by c. also $N \subseteq K$ (replace in the entire argument $N$ by $K$, or use that $N$ is minimal normal). So $K=N$.